# Able to Focus on element but cannot Click on it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am using a very poorly designed document management portal at my work called *Team Binder*. It's mainly used by government bodies and perhaps that is why it is one the least user friendly one. Anyhow, there is a button in the top right hand corner of the page which says '*Show Thread*'. Clicking on which will expand the conversation tree for that particular email.

[image]

And here is the HTML code for this button:

```
<a onclick="javascript:return LoadThreadView();" id="cmdShowThreadView" class="ShowMailObject" href="javascript:__doPostBack('cmdShowThreadView','')" style="text-decoration:none;">Show Thread</a>
```

What I want is to write a script to open the conversation tree by default (without the need of user's click). 
I am using Chrome and *ViolentMoneky* (for the sake of JavaScript coding).

The problem I have is, due to stupid *Team Binder*'s limitation, I can focus on the element but I cannot click on it.

I use following lines to focus on the desired button element:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      document.getElementById('cmdShowThreadView').focus()
  });
```

But as soon as I change it to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      document.getElementById('cmdShowThreadView').click()
  });
```

I get following error on page load event:

[image]

And this is despite I am already logged in.

Can anyone help me to achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of triggering a click event could you use below code?

It looks like they have two JS methods. First one is triggered on click event and then other one on href.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  LoadThreadView();
  __doPostBack('cmdShowThreadView','')
});
```

**Update**

Instead of above adding a delay helps to run this code after auto login

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
  setTimeout(function() { 
    LoadThreadView(); 
  }, 500); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I still get the same error message. The problem is caused by *LoadThreadView()* though.

Comment: because you are not logged in TeamBinder when page is loaded. Does it logs you automatically? Or you are using an API to perform login?

Comment: I am already logged in. If I hit F5 to refresh the screen, I still can see the content of the page i.e. I am still logged in. Isn't that right? To answer your second question, I am not using API to login.

Comment: No, basically this sounds like you have auto login enabled (you can try incognito window in chrome to validate). However, for above code which must be executing before auto login works it is throwing error. Hence, you need to find out a way to execute above code after login is done.

Comment: Now I have two questions: 1- Is there anyway I could trigger the code after login? 2- I cannot locate the definition for *LoadThreadView()* funtion in the page source. I can see it has been used several times but it has not been defined anywhere in the page source.

Comment: 1. This is something you may need to explore because if TeamBinder doesn't provide it as an option then the only option I see is a hack which may not work always. Something like  

`jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  setTimeout( function() {
    LoadThreadView();
    __doPostBack('cmdShowThreadView','')
  }, 3000);
});`
  

2. Try chrome console and type window. LoadThreadView(). See if you get that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167132/discussion-between-ankur-arora-and-bababarghi).